# How to force a vibrate on a android device with kotlin in a fragment class

Tags: android, kotlin

I thought I only have to insert `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />` to **`AndroidManifest.xml`** and a function with that content:

```kotlin
context?.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE).vibrate(30)
```

[Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/os/Vibrator)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    private fun Fragment.vibratePhone() {
        val vibrator = context?.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
           vibrator.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(200, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE))
           } else {
            vibrator.vibrate(200)
        }
}
```